# Solve this Differential Equation $[x\csc(\frac{y}{x})-y]dx+ydy=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$[x\csc(\frac{y}{x})-y]dx+ydy=0$

**My work**:

$[\csc(\frac{y}{x})-\frac{y}{x}]dx+\frac{y}{x}dy=0$

Let $u=\frac{y}{x}\rightarrow y=ux\rightarrow dy=udx+xdu$

$[\csc(u)-u]dx+u(udx+xdu)=0$

$[\csc(u)-u]dx+u^2dx+uxdu=0$

$\frac{u}{\csc(u)-u+u^2}du+\frac{dx}{x}=0$

Here I find two integration one of them I can't be solved, I do not know where I made a mistake.

Integration, which can not be resolved is

$\int\dfrac{u}{(\csc u)-u-u^2}du$

Comment: Because this integration does't have a solution @Amzoti

Comment: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1034378/solve-the-integral-int-fracx-csc-x-x-x2dx)

Comment: The source of this problem is homework in faculty @Amzoti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in implicit form is
$ \ln(x) = F(y/x) + c$ where
$$ F = - \int \dfrac{t\; dt}{\csc(t) + t^2 - t} $$
There's no way around the fact that this integral can't be done in closed form.

Comment: I think that this is the final result

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an $x$. It should be $[\csc(u)-u]dx+ux(udx+xdu)=0$

If you need anything else then tell me.

Actually nvm

Comment: $[\csc(u)-u]dx+u^2dx+uxdu)=0$

Comment: I am not missing an x.

Comment: I have to make sure and I did't find this mistake . @minusatwelfth

Comment: How did you get $\frac{u}{\csc(u)-u+u^2}du+\frac{dx}{x}=0$ ?

Comment: $[\csc(u)-u]dx+u(udx+xdu)=0 \rightarrow [\csc(u)-u]dx+u^2dx+uxdu=0 \rightarrow [\csc(u)-u+u^2]dx+uxdu=0 \rightarrow \frac{csc(u)-u+u^2}{u}dx=-xdu \rightarrow \frac{\frac{csc(u)-u+u^2}{u}dx}{dxdu}=-\frac{xdu}{dxdu}\rightarrow\frac{u}{\csc(u)-u+u^2}du+\frac{dx}{x}=0$
$ @minusatwelfth